# Setting height to 100%

Tags: html, height

I have a div that I want to be set to a 100% in height, and I know that the div can only have a percentage height if the cell its in has a height. I have a table and the column it is in can have a varied height depending on whats in the other columns in the row. So how do I still have a div with 100% height if the td has to have a 100% height? Do i have to set the table rows height as well? And if so how do i do it, because the height of the row can change.

```
  <table width="100%">
    <tr style="min-height:90px;">
      <td width="500px" class="innerBox2">
        INFO HERE (THIS IS THE COLUMN THAT CAN CHANGE THE HEIGHT DEPENDING ON HOW MUCH INFO IS IN HERE)
      </td>
      <td width="90px" style="height:100%" align="center" class="innerBox">
        <div class="innerBox2" style="height:100%">
          THIS IS THE DIV IM ASKING ABOUT
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: So you want the div to have 100% of the table height ?

Comment: Yes, but i think ive solved it. If i set entire table height to 100% then it seems to work, even though ive not set any heights above the table. Thanks for replying so quick tough

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `div` in a cell to have 100% of the table and you don't know or don't want to set the height on the table, you can always do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/2R9sm/

Css:

```
.innerBox2{
    background:#999;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.innerBox1{
    background:#333;
}
table{
    position:relative;
}
```

Html:

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr style="min-height:90px;">
      <td width="500px" class="innerBox1">
        INFO HERE (THIS IS THE COLUMN THAT CAN CHANGE THE HEIGHT DEPENDING ON HOW MUCH INFO IS IN HERE)
      </td>
      <td width="90px" style="height:100%" align="center" class="innerBox">
        <div class="innerBox2" style="height:100%">
          THIS IS THE DIV IM ASKING ABOUT
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Basically, using `position:absolute` on the `div` with `bottom:0; top:0;` will make it 100% of the `position:relative` parent (table in this case)